# FPS drops when using compton as non-root user

Tags: xubuntu, intel-graphics, root, compton

With an intel HD Graphics 5500 on Xubuntu 14.04 LTS (compton version git-v0.1-beta2.51-g65e655e-2014-11-30)

I'm experiencing a different behavior with compton :

- when started with non-root user => FPS drops to around 10-15 FPS
- when started as root => works as expected

I'm using that command to start compton :

```
compton --backend glx --vsync opengl-swc
```

(same issue with xrander backend and drm vsync method).

On another computer (intel HD Graphics 5000) running the same OS and compton version it works like a charm with a non-root user.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the solution to my problem.

A compton.conf file was present under the normal user account .config folder. This file was containing extra parameters which was causing the issue.
Because the root account has not that file compton was not using it.

```
backend = "glx";
paint-on-overlay = true;
glx-no-stencil = true;
glx-no-rebind-pixmap = true; <= removing this line solved my problem
vsync = "opengl-swc";
```